# Yii 2 url action

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a simple question maybe an idiot one but is it possible to have an action in another one ? 
I have an 'Administration' controller and an 'actionUser'. This action allows an admin to manage the users of the app. All users are displayed with a gridview, and in the 'ActionColumn' there is a possibilty to view and edit the user.

My question is : Is it possible to put manage the actionView in the actionUser.

Thanks !

**---EDIT---**

I have actionUsers which mangage the dataProvider for the gridView and pagination. This action (for now) do not receive any parameters. I want to manage the view and the editing of the user in this action. To call this action I have to get the URL `administration/users` and when I click on the button to view a user I have `administration/users/view?id=1`

I thought to add parameters to my action to have

```
public function actionUsers($action, $id)
```

but when I want to display all user it fails. Then something weird is the ?id=1 because view is not considered as a parameter but as an action in the controller users (I think). The only parameter is id for now.

I really need help please

Comment: Maybe it's better to use module/controller/action? Module Administration with some controllers (UserController in your case). And UserController can have simple `actionView()` and `actionIndex()` methods. Because action with $action parameter breaks standard controller behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I thought to do this, but I wanted to know if it was possible :)

Answer (score 1):

A way is base on actionColumn, in you gridview actionColumn you can customize your actionButton  this way

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'yuor_field1',
        .......
        .......
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:34px; font-size:22px;'],
            'template' => '{view}',               
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, [
                    'title' => 'view user',
                    ]);
                }
             ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action === 'view') {
                    $url = Url::to(['/administration/user/view', 'id' =>$model->id]);
                return $url;
                }
            }
        ]
```

for calling the actionUser as you have (with two parameter)

```
public function actionUsers($action, $id)
```

you should pass both $action an $id in you url this way

```
if ($action === 'view') {
    $url = Url::to(['/administration/user/view', action'=> 'your_action', 'id' =>$model->id]);
....
```

or you should rearrange the code for splitting the action required in more controller/action function  .. in your controller

Comment: Thank's, that's what I did but imagine my url is administration/user/view?id=1 how can I manage the view action in the user action ?

Comment: In fact, the view is not the problem I understand how it works but it is in the controller that I do not understand. Do I have to consider that 'view' is a param and make conditions in the actionUser ?

Comment: explain better .. update your question adding the related code and a proper explanation of your need